# Kafka: dynamically query configurations

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to access the configuration values in `server.properties` without direct access to that file itself?

I thought that:

```
kafka-configs.sh --describe --entity-type topics --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

might give me what I want, but I did not see the values set in `server.properties`.  Just the following (I set 'ddos' as my own topic from `kafka-topics.sh`):

```
Configs for topics:ddos are
Configs for topics:__consumer_offsets are segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact
```

I was thinking I'd also see globally configured options, like this from the default configuration I have:

```
log.retention.hours=168
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you never found a way to do this? It seems the `kafka-configs.sh --describe ...` script only shows the per-topic overrides, and not the global defaults + per-topic overrides, which would be far more useful

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka 0.11, you can use the AdminClient [`describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-) API to retrieve configuration of brokers.

For example, skeleton code to retrieve configuration for broker 0:

```java
Properties adminProps = new Properties();
adminProps.load(new FileInputStream("admin.properties"));
AdminClient admin = KafkaAdminClient.create(adminProps);

Collection<ConfigResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
ConfigResource cr = new ConfigResource(Type.BROKER, "0");
resources.add(cr);
DescribeConfigsResult dcr = admin.describeConfigs(resources);
System.out.println(dcr.all().get());
```